# How to click an element // button with this kind of html code

Tags: javascript

```
<span id="cart-update">
   <span class="cart-button">add to cart</span>
</span>
```

how do I click this button

I have tried `document.getElementById('cart-update').click();` and `document.getElementsByClassName('cart-button').click();`

Comment: You have a mixture of jQuery and Javascript. Which does — not — work. It is `document.getElementById('cart-update').addEventListener('click', function…)`.

Comment: @AjAX. There is zero jQuery in his question.

Comment: [@CertainPerformance there is no `input` to `click()` on.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) Please show me in the RTFM link where to go.

Comment: @AjAX. You can just click on an element in one line of built-in Javascript. It doesn't matter if the element in question is an `input` or not. (Your link makes no reference to jQuery - it's completely unnecessary)

Comment: [@CertainPerformance Please explain how `click()` is — not — jQuery.](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Answer (score 0):

On newer browsers you can do this to fire an event:

```
var event = new Event("click", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

If you want support for older browsers, try this code that I made:

```
function fireEventOnElement(event_name, element, bubbles, cancelable) {
    if (typeof Event != "undefined") {
        console.log("Bla");
        var evt = new Event(event_name, {"bubbles":bubbles, "cancelable":cancelable});
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else if ("createEvent" in document) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(event_name, bubbles, cancelable);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event_name);
    }
}
```

Use it like this: `fireEventOnElement("click", document.getElementById('cart-update'), true, false);`

### Edit: I changed code because initEvent is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and pass the event with a handler function:

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns *HTMLCollection*. You have to use proper index:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('cart-button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('You have clicked');
});
```

```html
<span id="cart-update">
  <span class="cart-button">add to cart</span>
</span>
```

Though I prefer [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which will return the first matched element:

```js
document.querySelector('.cart-button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('You have clicked');
});
```

```html
<span id="cart-update">
  <span class="cart-button">add to cart</span>
</span>
```

You can use `onclick` like the following:

```js
document.querySelector('.cart-button').onclick = function(){
  alert('You have clicked');
};
```

```html
<span id="cart-update">
  <span class="cart-button">add to cart</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` return a collection , to get the element from it pass the `index`, and use `addEventListener` to add any event

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('cart-button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let getText = e.target.innerHTML;
  console.log(getText)
})
```

```html
<span id="cart-update">
  <span class="cart-button">add to cart</span>
</span>
```